# perform click within function while using toggle

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have this click event, which one first click makes image and div bigger, 2nd click i would like to add a flip effect to image, and 3rd click makes div and image small again

```
//CLICK EVENT-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                $(this).toggle(function()
                {
                    makes div and image bigger
                }, 
                function()  //2nd function for toggle
                {
                    var margin =$(".image1").width()/2;
                    var width=$(".image1").width();
                    var height=$(".image1").height();
                    $(".image2").stop().css({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'});
                    flip_image(this); 
                },
                function()  //3rd function for toggle
                {
                    Makes div and image smaller
                    function()
                    {
                        rotateByAmount(indexPointer, this);  //reset rotation
                    });
                });
//END CLICK EVENT-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Im trying to amend the function flip_image so when the 2nd click takes place  the `$(".image1").click(function()`

will run automatically`  ? is this possible?

```
function flip_image(thisImage) 
        {
                $(".image1").click(function(){
                    $(this).stop().animate({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'},{duration:500});
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".image2").stop().animate({width:''+width+'px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:'0px',opacity:'1'},{duration:500});
                    },500);
                });

                $(".image2").click(function(){
                    $(this).stop().animate({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'},{duration:500});
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".image1").stop().animate({width:''+width+'px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:'0px',opacity:'1'},{duration:500});
                    },500);
                });
        }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `$('.image1').trigger('click')` ? It basically trigger a click event on your jQuery object. http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: yeah thats its, thank